# NotFoundException исключение при запуске

Tags: android

При попытке запустить приложение на виртуальном устройстве на андроид 4 (API 17), выкидывает различные исключения о том что не может найти файлы ресурсов, хотя они на самом деле есть. На виртуальном устройстве с андроид 5, никаких проблем не возникает и все запускается. Как решается подобная проблема? Кто-то сталкиваться?

Ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.test.phone/ru.test.phone.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at ru.test.phone.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at ru.test.phone.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:15) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020055
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1958)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at ru.test.phone.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:15) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1955)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330) 
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425) 
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at ru.test.phone.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:15) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Разметка splash_Screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_phone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context="ru.test.phone.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_name" />

        <ru.test.phone.TextClockView
            android:id="@+id/txtTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="21:00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:font="RoundishToons.ttf" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_layout2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnAlphabet"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_blue_btn"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_alphabet" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnNumber"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_green"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_number" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnPhone"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_purple"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_phone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnMusicInstruments"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_orange"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_musical_instrument" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnNote"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_violet"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_note" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnKidsMusic"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_red"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_headphones" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_layout1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnAnimals"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_dark_blue"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_animals" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnColors"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_blue_btn"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_colors" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgBtnFigures"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/square_btn_yellow"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_figure" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Код splash

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Время в милесекундах, в течение которого будет отображаться Splash Screen
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
//        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // По истечении времени, запускаем главный активити, а Splash Screen закрываем
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashScreenActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Animation rotateAnimation = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        final ImageButton imgBtnAlphabet = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAlphabet);
        final ImageButton imgBtnNumber = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNumber);
        final ImageButton imgBtnPhone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnPhone);
        final ImageButton imgBtnMusicInstruments = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnMusicInstruments);
        final ImageButton imgBtnNote = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNote);
        final ImageButton imgBtnKidsMusic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnKidsMusic);
        final ImageButton imgBtnAnimals = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAnimals);
        final ImageButton imgBtnColors = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnColors);
        final ImageButton imgBtnFigures = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFigures);

        // устанавливаем один обработчик для всех кнопок
        imgBtnAlphabet.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnNumber.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnPhone.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnMusicInstruments.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnNote.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnKidsMusic.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnAnimals.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnColors.setOnClickListener(this);
        imgBtnFigures.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    // Метод для вращения элемента View
    public void rotate(View v) {
        rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate);
        v.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }

    // В зависимости от id View открываем соответствующее Activity
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i;

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgBtnAlphabet:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAlphabet));
                i = new Intent(this, AlphabetActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnNumber:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNumber));
                i = new Intent(this, NumberActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnPhone:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnPhone));
                i = new Intent(this, PhoneActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnMusicInstruments:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnMusicInstruments));
                i = new Intent(this, MusicInstrumentsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnNote:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnNote));
                i = new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnKidsMusic:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnKidsMusic));
                i = new Intent(this, KidsMusicActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnAnimals:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAnimals));
                i = new Intent(this, AnimalsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnColors:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnColors));
                i = new Intent(this, ColorsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.imgBtnFigures:
                rotate(findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFigures));
                i = new Intent(this, FiguresActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ок, попробую сейчас

Comment: Ну а вообще, он у вас ругается совсем не на то, что не может ресурсы найти. покажите код, где у вас происходит использование этого `layout`

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в вопрос коды

Comment: добавила в вопрос

Comment: не помогло очистка кеша и пересборка проекта

Comment: Размер android:background="@drawable/bg" какой?

Comment: 800 на 1300)).. Понимаю что большой, но разве из-за этого может быть такая ошибка

Comment: Такие ошибки иногда возникают из-за больших изображений используемых для фона. Попробуйте, ради эксперимента, убрать фон, или заменить на что-то поменьше

Comment: Уменьшила размеры до 200 на 325 все равно ошибки

Comment: если фон совсем убрать, то работает. Но я бы хотела именно этот фон :). Кстати если фоны убрать, то потом начинает ругаться на фоны кнопок в MainActivity а там не такие уж большие размеры 150 на 150

Comment: У вас этот фон используется не только в сплеше, но и в MainActivity. Так что ошибка может просто перемещаться дальше по коду.

Comment: Я везде убирала фон. Я понимаю что в MainActivity тоже ругается

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin

Comment: там советуют добавить vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true, а у меня уже добавлено это

Comment: Ну там в обсуждении много интересного. В частности, `buildToolsVersion` у вас чему равно?

Comment: 25.0.1 стоит...